# Combining Audio and Video file in python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess, wav, avi

I'm trying to understand how to us ffmpeg to combine video and audio files in python. I want to combine a .avi file and a .wav file to create a final .avi file. Is this the right approach? I'm confused by the ffmpeg syntax.
Any help would be great.

I was looking through this for help:
https://wiki.libav.org/Snippets/avconv#Combine_audio_and_video_file

```
import ffmpeg
import subprocess

cmd = 'ffmpeg -i inputvideo.avi -i inputaudio.wav -c:v copy -c:a aac output_video_and audio.avi'
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)                                     # "Muxing Done
print('Muxing Done')
```